# Enter the same value for the entire year

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table Payments

```
 Client   Dt        Payment
     1     201311      10
     1     201312       0
     2     201401       0
     1     201402       0
     1     201403       0
```

And i want select where i add to this select column "OwnerFlag", where if the client has paid in that year then in all rows for that year for that client will be OwnerFlag 1, otherwise its 0. So the final select should look like :

```
Client   Dt        Payment     OwnerFlag
     1     201311      10        1
     1     201312       0        1
     2     201401       0        0
     1     201402       0        0
     1     201403       0        0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that `DT` is a `datetime` column:

```
SELECT Client, Dt, Payment,
       OwnerFlag = CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   (
                      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Payments p1
                      WHERE p1.ClientID = p.ClientID 
                        AND YEAR(p1.Dt) = YEAR(p.Dt)
                        AND p1.Pament <> 0
                   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.Payments p
```